# Xtext: cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: jvm, dsl, xtext, xtend

I have strange error in my code:

```
import dsltest.models.Plant    
import dsltest.controllers.PlantController.create

package dsltest.assemblers {

assembler PlantAssembler : Plant {

    state CREATES
        create => PENDING
    end

    state PENDING

    end
}
}
```

Error:
 "dsltest.controllers.PlantController.create cannot be resolved to a type." occurs at import(second line). There is no error at first line import.

"create" is a method encapsulated by controller-"PlantController"

I tried to clean project, but it didn't help. Please someone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a **static** import declaration to import static members:

```
import static dsltest.controllers.PlantController.create
```

Otherwise `dsltest.controllers.PlantController.create` is treated as a reference to `JvmDeclaredType`.

Comment: Is the method static? Do you still get the same error?

Comment: The method must be static. You cannot import instance methods, since you need an instance of PlantController class first.

Comment: Default semantic of XImportSection is similar to java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5. As you can see it does not implicitly create an instance of the imported type and put it on the scope of the declared type.

Do you infer a class for PlantAssembler and a method for each state? If so, you can add a field with extension modifier of type PlantController to this class.